# C++ Int to Array without Libs

Tags: c++

Good Morning,
how can I convert a `int a = 325;` to a array `int b[2]`, without a lib?
I mean this so `b[0] = 3;`, `b[1] = 2;` and `b[2] = 5;`

Bye

Comment: Yes you can! Look for integer division and modulo operations.

Comment: its simply `digit separation`

Comment: And why 'without a lib' ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Most probably, because their teacher told them to do it with simple math operations only.

Comment: You're going to want to make `b` large enough to hold 3 values.  As you have it declared, accessing `b[2]` is out of bounds.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like:

```
int x = a;
int i = 0;
while (x > 0)
{
    b[i++] = x % 10;
    x /= 10;
}
```

Comment: This will make b[0]=5, not 3 as requested. (Reducing this problem to the problem of reversing the elements of an array.)

Comment: That's fine though, the algorithm for reversing the elements of an array is well known. Or you can make two passes, one to count the number of digits, and then a second to write the digits to the correct array slots.

Comment: pssst hint : count the length of numbers and start adding digits from end to start of array.

Comment: Yes, but an answer that starts with divving before modding would be better than mine

Comment: which what @rajenpandit done in his answer

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
int i=100;
for(int x=0;x<3;x++)
{
    b[x]=a/i;
    a=a%i;
    i=i/10;
}
```

Comment: This works only for variables which is within [100, 999] boundary btw.